# UnauthorizedAccess error in VS while creating angular new file

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

I have install node, npm, angular cli but while creating new project in vs UnauthorizedAccess error is showing

Please someone help me
Thank You,

[Error picture is attached hear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ar4q2.jpg)

Comment: Can you try running this command in a regular terminal instead of powershell?

Comment: yes, I run this command in VS terminal. would I run this command in powershell?

Comment: Well, your vscode terminal is a powershell terminal. That‘a why I asked if you switch to cmd for example.

Answer (score 0):

- right click on this pc and select properties.
- click on advanced system setting.
- click on environmental variable.
- select path variable from system variable.
- click on edit button, and add %AppData%\npm and %ProgramFiles%\nodejs\ at top of the list after that click ok
- restart your system.
- after restarting open visual studio code

Comment: Thanks for your Comment I follow these steps but I have the same error.